# Convert URL to string and extract part of to it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage/someotherpage#somesection
```

I'm trying to convert a given URL from `window.location.href` to a string and extract part of it to a variable
using regex. `'/(\#.*)/g'`

The URLs all contain a `#` and all I basically want to do is dynamically store the characters that come after the hash, 
whether or not it includes the hash.

So far my attempts haven't worked:

```
var pageSection = window.location.href;
    newSection = pageSection.match('/(\#.*)/g');
console.log(newSection);
```

just returns `null`. My other attempts have just returned the whole URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `pageSection.match(/#.*/g)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845913/javascript-simple-regexp-doesnt-work: *make it a regular expresison, not a string*.

Comment: Why not just use `window.location.hash.substring(1);` If you use `.hash` on `window.location` it will return `#somesection` so `substring(1)` will remove the `#` from the returned string giving you the hash value only.

Comment: That didn't work Wiktor

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you! That worked a treat!

Comment: @Lanlé a tip for next time. Just `console.log()` the object and you can see what properties that object has. Example `console.log(window.location)` will show you. `search` - `pathname` - `href` - `hostname` ect...